# How to convert bytes 32 array?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I tried do this, but this return  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

```
 // Convert bytes to address
 function fromBytes(bytes32[] _additionalArgs) public view returns (address[]){
      address[] memory path = new address[](_additionalArgs.length);

      for(uint i = 0; i > _additionalArgs.length; i++){
         path[i] = address(_additionalArgs[i]);
      }

      return path;
  }
```

I need return array with addresses!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never executes.

```
for(uint i = 0; i > _additionalArgs.length; i++){
```

`i` begins at `0`, and the loop condition is `i > _additionalArgs.length`, which can't ever be true. You almost certainly meant to use `<` instead:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < _additionalArgs.length; i++){
```

With that change, I believe your code should work.

Comment: Oh :)

Thank You!